# Can "at all" be used in an affirmative sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The real risk of cbdcs to the financial system may be that they eventually precipitate a new kind of run: on the idea that banks need to exist "at all".

What does 'at all' refer to here? Does it give the sentence a negative meaning?

Comment: _At all_ is a Negative Polarity Item. It isn't negative itself, but its use shows that there is a negative meaning in the sentence. In this case, it's the idea of "a run", in the sense of a "run on a bank", meaning general loss of credibility for deposits. This is metaphorized into doubt about whether banks need to exist. _At all_ in such a context is merely a strengthening of the negation implied by "a run on". A very confusing text, but then it's finance, and that's sposta be confusing because you're placing a bet.

Answer (score 2):

I think the author of the text meant to write

> The real risk of cbdcs to the financial system may be that they eventually precipitate a new kind of run: ***promoting the doubt/question whether*** banks need to exist "at all".

Yes, ***at all*** can be used with an affirmative verb in direct and indirect questions:

> Do you know her at all?

> I wonder if/whether she read my essay at all.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wonder exact meaning or synonym of "at all" actually.

Comment: Do you know her at all? = Do you know her even one tiny bit?      I wonder if/whether she read my essay at all.= I wonder whether she read even one line of it/even once. Now in your example I think it means 'the question whether banks should _even_ exist.'

Comment: _At all_ is a 'minimum'. It requires a [negative trigger](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) like a question or an overt negative or an _if_ clause, and when it occurs it refers to the least bit of whatever is at issue, including activities: _if he comes at all, ..._ means "I doubt that he'll come, but in the unlikely event that he does come, ..."